# issue in adding physical volume to volume group lvm

Tags: lvm

Can anyone please help me fix the problem to add more GB to vg?

lsblk Output

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                 8:0    0  128G  0 disk
|-sda1              8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot/efi
|-sda2              8:2    0  500M  0 part /boot
|-sda3              8:3    0    2M  0 part
`-sda4              8:4    0  127G  0 part
  |-rootvg-tmplv  253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  /tmp
  |-rootvg-usrlv  253:1    0   10G  0 lvm  /usr
  |-rootvg-optlv  253:2    0    2G  0 lvm  /opt
  |-rootvg-homelv 253:3    0    1G  0 lvm  /home
  |-rootvg-varlv  253:4    0   35G  0 lvm  /var
  `-rootvg-rootlv 253:5    0   12G  0 lvm  /
```

```
# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  rootvg   1   6   0 wz--n- <63.02g <1.02g
```

```
 #lvs
  LV     VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  homelv rootvg -wi-ao----  1.00g
  optlv  rootvg -wi-ao----  2.00g
  rootlv rootvg -wi-ao---- 12.00g
  tmplv  rootvg -wi-ao----  2.00g
  usrlv  rootvg -wi-ao---- 10.00g
  varlv  rootvg -wi-ao---- 35.00g
```

I need to use the unused GB's from sda4 and extend the size of rootvg-varlv
can anyone please suggest me the steps to do that?

Comment: What is the result of `pvs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't used all the available space in `/dev/sda4` for your Physical Volume (PV). There's 127GB assigned here:

> ```
> `-sda4              8:4    0  127G  0 part
> ```

and although the LVs add up only to approximately 62GB:

> ```
> |-rootvg-tmplv  253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  /tmp
> |-rootvg-usrlv  253:1    0   10G  0 lvm  /usr
> |-rootvg-optlv  253:2    0    2G  0 lvm  /opt
> |-rootvg-homelv 253:3    0    1G  0 lvm  /home
> |-rootvg-varlv  253:4    0   35G  0 lvm  /var
> `-rootvg-rootlv 253:5    0   12G  0 lvm  /
> ```

the VG claims it has only around 1GB available out of 63GB:

> ```
> rootvg   1   6   0 wz--n- <63.02g <1.02g
> ```

Try extending the PV. (As an aside, did you resize `/dev/sda` and/or `/dev/sda4` at some point? It looks like that's a possibility.)

```
pvresize /dev/sda4
```

Assuming it reports a successful increase in size, `vgs` should immediately show the extra available space, which you can then allocate as appropriate. Here's an example showing how to add a further 10 GiB to the `varlv` LV:

```
lvextend --size +10G --resizefs /dev/rootvg/varlv
```

Don't throw everything at `varlv` just because you can; just assign what you need right now. You can add more later if you need it, but by holding some back you can increase the sizes of other LVs should that become necessary. It's much much easier to add space than to (safely) remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vgextend command on your vg and then extend the lv with lvextend or lvresize. The problem is that usually you can not extend vg with size , just with another/new vg .Other problem is that usually it is somewhat risky to run those on live systems, thus i'd would suggest to do so on usb boot.

```
vgextend command:

pvcreate /dev/sdX
vgextend rootvg /dev/sdX
# sdX being new drive that you are extending the rootvg with -> it can be even usb device, although ssd is prefered
# just to clarify -> not the same usb that you are booting from.

lvextend command:

lvextend -L+20G /dev/rootvg/rootlv
# you need path to lv that you are extending.
```

Comment: I think he should resize it's PV as it doesn't contains all /dev/sda4. vgs says 63 GB while /dev/sda4 is 127 GB. then he will be able to extend any LV directly. the pvresize without options resizes physical volume to the size the operating system reports for the underlying partition. `pvresize /dev/sda4`

Comment: The info in the question and the previous answer indicate that the VG is not utilizing all the space provided in the PV. `pvresize` should take care of this without adding in a new partition.