# Extended virtual harddisk in CentOS VM, not showng in df -h even after applying resize operation in GParted

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, virtual-memory, gparted, hyper-v

I've extended the virtual drive of my CentOS VM (Windows Hyper-V manager) from 25GB to 40GB.

Also used GParted to resize the existing `/dev/sda2`  to use the entire newly unallocated 15GB space (clicked 'apply all operations').

[image: Gparted window]

But it's still not showing up with `df -h`. Any other steps I need to take?

[image: Results of df -h:]

Comment: You're not using the Proper tools to verify the size.  `/dev/sda2`s size should be verified with a compatible lvm tool that will properly parse `/dev/mapper/centos-root`.  Did you initialize it properly.  See [RedHat's 5 Easy Commands for LVM Resize](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple)

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768835/100397) is for an almost identical situation. They are using sda4. You are using sda2